What is Sørensen–Dice coefficient formula for 3 sets?
What is actually Sørensen–Dice coefficient formula for 3 sets? for 2 sets, it is:
$$\frac{2 \cdot |A \cap B|}{|A| + |B|}$$
But for 3 sets? is this right? :
$$\frac{3 \cdot |A \cap B \cap C|}{|A| + |B| + |C|}$$
I searched but I cannot find an exact answer

I don't think there is such a thing - it's defined for two sets.  What you gave would be a reasonable generalization though.
